# attached volume of a FreeBSD amazon ec2 instance does not show up

Tags: amazon-ec2, freebsd, amazon-ebs

I have followed the steps in the documentation, created a new EBS volume and attached it to the instance (I only have one). I rebooted and tried shutdown/start, but the device does not show up inside the FreeBSD instance. I only have `/dev/ada0` and `/dev/ada0a`.

Are there maybe any other steps necessary to make this work for a FreeBSD instance? I don't know anything about the abstraction layers amazon is using. I guess a problem could be that FreeBSD **device naming** is different.

Comment: FreeBSD have disk devices named `da` - do you have any in the `/dev`?

Comment: No, it turns out the device is named `xbd5`... this wasn't documented anywhere. And it didn't show up via gpart and friends either.

Comment: Oh, I've forgot you have a virtual machine. Under Xen freebsd see `xbd` devices, under Proxmox -  `vtbd` and so on.

Answer (score 3):

@hasufell, your comment is correct - the device on BSD instances is not named using Linux/std AWS naming. I got the same device name you did - `xbd5` - but you can confirm what the device name is by reviewing the system logs for `<Virtual Block Device>` entries (either grep dmesg/messages or through AWS Instance control panel - select instance, then Actions -> Instance Settings -> Get System Log). A 100GB device might show up like this in the log:

```
xbd5: 102400MB <Virtual Block Device> at device/vbd/51792 on xenbusb_front0
```

You can also run `sysctl kern.disks` and you should see something like:

```
kern.disks: xbd5 ada0
```

... where `ada0` is your first EBS volume and `xbd5` is your new attached volume.

Then just mount your new volume:

```
newfs /dev/xbd5
mkdir /yourvol
mount /dev/xbd5 /yourvol
```

Add to `/etc/fstab` to mount at boot:

```
/dev/xbd5 /yourvol ufs rw 0 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add a partition number if the first partition is not of type "freebsd-ufs". For example, if you have a boot volume from machine A that you want to mount, for maintenance purposes, to machine B, then your first partition may be type `freebsd-boot`, and `mount /dev/<device> /yourvol` will fail with a "No such file or directory" error.

As a general solution, regardless of whether working with a blank or populated new volume and whether the first partition is or isn't "freebsd-ufs" type, you can add the partition to the mount operation as follows:

1. Run `gpart show` to locate the first partition that is type "freebsd-ufs"
2. Run `mount /dev/<device>p<partition> /yourvol`

For example, if `gpart show` displays the following:

```
=>       3  31457269  xbd5  GPT  (15G)
         3       111     1  freebsd-boot  (56K)
       114      1600     2  efi  (800K)
      1714  31455558     3  freebsd-ufs  (15G)
```

then you would mount with:

```
mount /dev/xbd5p3 /yourvol
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very useful!!